# MOSFET Amplifier?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

I'm trying to create an amplifier circuit using a n channel MOSFET and I can't seem to get the results I'm looking for. I'm trying to amplify an AC signal up to the +/- Vcc but I keep getting strange outputs. Here's my latest trial:

[image: MOSFET circuit]

I've gotten similar results no matter what configuration I try. It's always a signal that is greatly positive or greatly negative when it should not be exceeding the Vcc

Comment: Have you tried simulating a current mirror instead of a current source?

Comment: Based on what I just read about current mirrors, it doesn't seem like that is what i'm looking for. I'm basically trying to create an op amp using mosfets.

Comment: A current source isn't real, which is why you aren't getting real results.

Comment: What do you suggest then? Because it doesn't seem like a current mirror will do what I want either.

Comment: To clarify, I'm just trying to take a low AC voltage and amplify it. Somewhere along the lines of +/- 5V to +/- 40V. I'm doing this without an op amp because the best one I could find wouldn't go past +/- 35V for its power supply

Comment: Using an op amp doesn't answer your question about your circuit, but it will solve your problem.  Use a high voltage op amp like the LTC6090 from Linear Technologies.  Supply Range: ±4.75V to ±70V (140V)

Comment: Unfortunately, that has too low of a max output current for my needs. 

What I'm trying to do is drive a 50W transducer. The specs call for 40kHz at 100-120V. Couldn't find an Op Amp that would operate within those constraints. I have a DC power supply capable of putting out +/-100V and adequate current

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a strange result.  The *ideal* constant current source in the source circuit can have *any* voltage across and produce the specified current.  In fact, V2 is essentially irrelevant.

It appears that you've specified that the current source produces a 0.5A constant current.  Since the current source is ideal, the voltage across it will be whatever it needs to be such that there is 0.5A through the attached circuit.  It 'doesn't care' what your supply voltages are - not one bit.

But this isn't remotely physical so, the first thing you should is get rid of the ideal current source.  Also, if you want voltage gain, you shouldn't be using a common-drain configuration, as you have drawn, since the voltage gain is less than 1.

Honestly, I think it's likely that you're in over your head on this.  For voltage gain, you probably want a common-source configuration and, for sure, forget that ideal current source.

Comment: I figured the current source was the problem. But I was originally trying a common source configuration and was running into similar problems. 

I am definitely over my head on this. Analog circuits isn't my field of study and transistors are beyond me

Comment: [mosfet2](http://i.imgur.com/IYwv2Oj.jpg)

Here's my common source set up. The problem is the wave has a very small peak to peak. I want it to be +/- 40V

Comment: @user3427168,  you will almost certainly need a multi-transistor design with negative feedback to produce a *linear*, large-signal voltage amplifier capable of +/-40V output.

Comment: Is there a particular name for such a configuration? Can't seem to find anything helpful through google